# How to change or disable hotkey for VMware Player?

Tags: hotkeys, vmware-player

I'm running VMware for some older design apps that can run only on Windows XP. 
One of those apps uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> shortcuts
to perform various tasks.

The issue is that VMware player uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> as a hotkey to grant control back to the host OS.

Is there a way to disable this or change it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was having the same problem, and a little research led me to the “Modifying the hot key setting in VMware Server (1008036)” article on the VMware Knowledge Base site (archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140123174014/http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1008036)).

It shows how to modify the `preferences.ini` file to make the hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, and indicates that other key combinations can also be set. 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> was fine for me, so I tried that and it works:

> #### Purpose
>
> This article provides steps to customize the hot key preferences in
>   VMware Server 2.0.
>
> #### Resolution
>
> The Remote Console does not provide an interface control to set the
>   hot key settings. You must configure hot keys in the user preferences
>   files.
>
> To configure hot keys in the user preferences file:
>
> **Note**: If you have other VMware products installed, these changes affect the preferences of those products as well.
>
> 1. Open the preferences file in a text editor.
>
>    The file is located in one of the following locations:
>
>    - Windows XP and Windows Server 2000 –
>        `C:\Documents and Settings\[username]\Application Data\VMware\preferences.ini`
>    - Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, Windows 8, and Windows Server 2012 – `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\VMware\preferences.ini`
>
>      - (`%AppData%\VMware\preferences.ini` may work for either of the above.)
>    - Unix/Linux – `~/.vmware/preferences`
> 2. Add the following lines to the file:
>
>    ```
>    pref.hotkey.gui = "false"
>    pref.hotkey.shift = "true"
>    pref.hotkey.control = "true"
>    pref.hotkey.alt = "true"
>    ```
>
>    This combination sets the hot keys
>      to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. 
>      Other settings yield different combinations.
> 3. Save the file and restart the Remote Console.

Reportedly, the `pref.hotkey.gui` line refers to the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key.

Comment: Worth mentioning that "pref.hotkey.gui" refers to the Windows key; this wasn't immediately obvious to me.

Comment: On Windows 7 and Windows 8 the preferences file can be found in Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\VMware\preferences.ini

Comment: Thanks, it work perfectly on my VMWare Player 4

Answer (score 5):

If you change VMX-file parameters (preferences.ini - settings), you can do what you want...

> ```
> pref.hotkey.shift = "true"    
> pref.hotkey.alt = "true"    
> pref.hotkey.control = "true"
>
> pref.hotkey.disableExitFullScreenOnHotkeyRelease
> pref.hotkey.disableHotkeyDelete
> pref.hotkey.disableHotkeyEscape
> pref.hotkey.disableHotkeyInsert
> pref.hotkey.leftAlt
> pref.hotkey.leftControl
> pref.hotkey.leftShift
> pref.hotkey.rightAlt
> pref.hotkey.rightControl
> pref.hotkey.rightShift
> ```
>
> In Linux-VMs you may not like the usual CTRL + ALT combination –
>   use this for CTRL + ALT + SHIFT

The source of the above is [here](http://sanbarrow.com/vmx/vmx-preferences-ini.html), which contains information
regarding other things you can do with `preferences.ini`.