# Vmware Player keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vmware

I'm wondering whether there is any possibility to configure keyboard shortcuts in Vmware Player.

I'm mostly interested in: Cycle multiple monitors and cycling through running virtual machines.

Comment: [These](http://allhotkeys.com/vmware_keyboard_shortcuts.html) don't work?  

_Ctrl-Alt-Tab_ - Switch among open virtual machines while mouse and keyboard input are grabbed.  
_Ctrl-Tab_ - Switch among open virtual machines while mouse and keyboard input are not grabbed. VMware Workstation must be the active application.  
_Ctrl-Shift-Tab_ - Switch among open virtual machines while mouse and keyboard input are not grabbed. VMware Workstation must be the active application.

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to work on Wmware Player.

Comment: Seems to be answered lately : http://superuser.com/questions/234918/how-to-change-or-disable-hot-key-for-vmware-player