# How do you disable the hot key for resetting a VMware Workstation virtual machine?

Tags: vmware-workstation

How do you disable the hot key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, which resets the VMware Workstation virtual machine?

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio and I'm going for its <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> hot key, but occasionally I'm instead triggering the Workstation one, which is a wee bit annoying.

This is for the VMware Workstation product, rather than the VMware Player, so I don't think it's a duplicate of [this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/234918/how-to-change-or-disable-hot-key-for-vmware-player).

Comment: Are you using it on linux?

Comment: @avirk Nope, I'm using it on my Windows laptop

Comment: See in the `C` drive where ***VMware** installed. Is there under `.vmware/prefrences` can you see `hint.vmui.reset` option?

Comment: Can you tell also which version of Windows you are running?

Comment: @SteveC: Please don’t tamper with the automatically inserted text until the question has been reopened.

Comment: @BenN: Please don’t tamper with the automatically inserted text until the question has been reopened.

Comment: @fixer1234: I was already working on it!

Comment: @Scott: Didn't mean to deprive you of your fun.  I can roll it back if you want to do it again.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234: No need; I'm fine.  :-)  ⁠

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Windows XP then go to the following path

> C:\Document and Settings\your username\Application Data\VMware\preferences.ini

And then add the line and save it.

`hint.vmui.reset = "true"`

Now open VMware Console back up and go to **Help>Hints>Show Enabled Hints**.

If you are using the Windows 7 then I think this file must be in

> C:\Users\username\AppData\VMware\prefrences.ini

And do the same for this too.. Hope this will help.

Information drawn form this [source](http://contentment.org/2006/11/vmwares-worst-feature-ctrlr-to.html).

Comment: Sorry, but the details on the page correct this, the actual setting is ... hint.vmui.reset = "true" ... which displays the "Are you sure dialog", so you don't reset the virtual machine

Comment: So does it helped? I have fixed the wrong keyword.

Comment: Yeap it works with hint.vmui.reset so I've accepted the answer. Thanks for finding this tip, it's been really bugging me

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. The question pertains to a different product and is about another topic. The path in the other article is correct while the path in the accepted answer for this question is incorrect for Windows 7. The correct path is: %APPDATA%\VMware\preferences.ini